# Restrict the number of strings appended

Tags: c++

I have CString  temp = CString temp1 +CString temp2 + CString temp3 + CString temp4 + CString 5;
(no more than 5 should be appended).
Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Close vote on the wrong question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since `CString` is a MS internal class, no, you can't restrict concatenation everywhere in the code.

If there's a particular block where you want to do this, you can simply provide a function with 5 parameters:

```
 CString concatenate(const CString& temp1 = CString(),
                     const CString& temp2 = CString(),
                     const CString& temp3 = CString(),
                     const CString& temp4 = CString(),
                     const CString& temp5 = CString(),);
```

Comment: ok.can this be done using a loop?  each time CString temp should concatenate with  temp1,then temp2,..temp5.

Answer (score -1):

Use `String.Format` to Append the String like..

```
String _iString = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", param1,param2,param3,param4,param5)
```

Then use `_iString` in your code....

Comment: What's wrong with `operator +` to concatenate? I don't think this is what he's asking.

Comment: -1 This is tagged `c++`.